# Transaction in HIbernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In the below code:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("student.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    //Transaction tran = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(student);
    //tran.commit();
    session.flush();
    session.close();
```

Irrespective of whether I comment/uncomment the Transaction, they works fine i.e. without transaction also save operation is performed successfully. But whn I check the documentation then they always use the transaction before insert update delete. Any specific reasons for the same? Am I missing something?

Please let me know about this. I am fairly confused :(

Regards,

Comment: DML Commands need explicit commit.. Did you check with Insert, Delete , Update commands??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you always use auto-commit, it may harm your db. Let's say you want to commit bunch of work at a time. In this situation, you need to create transaction and commit all of your work after finishing all the job. For example, you need to do lots of database access for an atomic work for you. In that case, you need to do all the work in your transaction and commit all the work.

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

// do some work
tx.commit();
```

Of course with your catch blocks.

Comment: ok so what I understand from your post is: 1) If I don't use transaction then an implicit commit will happen whereas if I use transaction, then I am commiting the data explicitly. 2) Implicit commit is harmfull, hence Transaction shoulld be used for commiting explicitly. Please let me know if i get you correct. Please add something if I am wrong. 
Regards,

Comment: Harmful might not be the correct word because it's about your design. Transactions are group of data access operations. If more than database operation is one unit work for you, then you need to commit all of them together which means they have to be in a transaction.

Comment: I have a doubt from your first response: Suppose I read some data, begin one transaction then also there is a probability of the data getting updated inside the transaction right? Can you please explain this line?

Comment: Don't be confused with my example. What I want to mean is that unit of work. You have an operation which is an atomic operation and it needs to do more than one db operation. In this case, you put them in a transaction. (It's like do all or not do anything)

Comment: Ok the term `do all or not do anything` is clear. I tried a couple of consecutive save operations, intentionally I did some violation in the second save operation. If I add the transaction, then neither the valid nor the invalid save operation rows are getting added. But again if I remove the transaction, then the first valid save is getting inserted but the second one is not getting inserted. Other than this multiple DB operation scenario, is there some other use of this transaction? Please let me know. Thanks for the reply

Comment: It would be better if you take a loot at here https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions. You will find some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode?_sscc=t)
The article is from JBOSS

One thing I believe that If you do not use transaction(at some point you may need it, if no need atomic operation) then any db related operation hits database. It makes the system crazy slow. If you do transaction, then hibernate does all the operation in the same transaction by one time hitting to db . At some point, somewhere I read that before.

Answer (score 0):

i think the non-select queries in hibernate are executing multiple queries(or using multiple operations ) thats why we need transactions to execute them.